# Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty -Error happens while checking JObject using LinQ

Tags: c#, linq, json.net

I have a JObject object which has Json data. I need to collect all KeyValuePairs of whichever has `"state": true`. Before I read the value, I want to make sure that the JObject has at least one KeyValuePairs with JToken (Value) has `"state": true`.
Below is my JSON:

```
{  
  "AAA": {
    "state": false,
    "version": "1.1.14202.0",
    "result": null,
    "update": "20171018"
  },
  "BBB": {
    "state": true,
    "version": "3.10.1.18987",
    "result": null,
    "update": "20171018"
  },
  "CCC": {
    "state": true,
    "version": "1.1.1.2",
    "result": null,
    "update": "20171018"
  }
}
```

And the below is the code currently I'm checking with, which is throwing an exception saying `Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty`**:**

```
JObject jsonData = //JSON data;
List<JToken> tokens = jsonData .Children().ToList();
if (tokens.Any(each => each["state"].ToString().ToLower().Contains("true")))
{
  List<JToken> tokensWithStateTrue = tokens.Where(each => each["state"].ToString().ToLower().Contains("true")).ToList();
}
```

Please help me and correct the LinQ statement to read only JTokens with *state* as *true*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This worked for me, looks like you're missing an extra call to Children() to access the properties you need.

```
//parse JSON and grab it's children. 
var jsonData = JObject.Parse(json).Children();

List<JToken> tokens = jsonData .Children().ToList();
```

or

```
List<JToken> tokens = jsonData .Children().Children().ToList();
if (tokens.Any(each => each["state"].ToString().ToLower().Contains("true")))
{
    List<JToken> tokensWithStateTrue = tokens.Where(each => each["state"].ToString().ToLower().Contains("true")).ToList();
}
```

[image]

Alternatively you could do this. The code below will return a dictionary with only your states with true values. Otherwise, it will return an empty dictionary if you have no true values.

```
var dictionaryTokensWithTrueValues = jsonData.Children()
.Select(u => u as JProperty)
.Where(v => v.Value["state"].ToString().ToLower().Contains("true"))
.ToDictionary(k => k.Name, v => v.Value);

//check if you have any true values
if (dictionaryTokensWithTrueValues.Count() > 0)
{
     //do something with true states here
     var accessBBB = dictionaryTokensWithTrueValues["BBB"]; //{{"state": true,"version": "3.10.1.18987","result": null,"update": "20171018"}}
}
else
{ 
     //no true states. Do something else
}
```