# Parsing JSON and applying filter

Tags: c#, json, linq

I've `ObservableCollection<dynamic>` called myJSON in C# having 4 items as follows:

```
[
    {
      "name": "A",
      "location": "NY"
    },

    {
      "name": "B",
      "location": "NJ"
    },
    {
      "name": "A",
      "location": "NY"
    },

    {
      "name": "D",
      "location": "MA"
    }
]
```

I need to be able to apply a filter query like say where name="A" and location="NY" and then get back 2 records from above.

I tried code like below but I was only able to parse one record at a time from the above collection. And also the 2nd line seems to error out with a message:

> "Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue."

```
JObject json = JObject.Parse(myJSON[0].ToString()); 
var match = json.Values<JProperty>().Where(m => m.Value["name"].ToString() == "A" && m.Value["location"].ToString() == "NY").FirstOrDefault();
```

Thanks.

Comment: The JSON in the sample collection does not look like a properly constructed JSON array

Comment: While in non-answer by [Jdog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11539758/jdog) they suggested some information in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49254281/cannot-access-child-value-on-newtonsoft-json-linq-jproperty-error-happens-while may be helpful this question itself can't be answered without actual [MCVE]. Since there is no actual JSON provided it is unclear if code indeed missing some `.Child` calls or something else.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Have corrected the format. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace NameLoc
{
    class Program
    {

        class NameLoc 
        {
            public string Name;
            public string Location;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var lst = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<NameLoc>>(File.ReadAllText("NameLoc.json"));
            var selLst = from sel in lst where sel.Name == "A" && sel.Location == "NY" select sel;
            foreach (var it in selLst)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{it.Name}, {it.Location}");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

And then be sure to add a file "NameLoc.Json" Set build Action Copy To output I found errors in your json corrected below. Add Newtonsoft.json to pkgs

```
[
  {
    "name": "A",
    "location": "NY"
  },
  {
    "name": "B",
    "location": "NJ"
  },

  {
    "name": "A",
    "location": "NY"
  },

  {
    "name": "D",
    "location": "MA"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, let's fix json format. If you are talking about collection or array then your json format should be like this:

```
[
    {
      "name": "A",
      "location": "NY"
    },
    {
      "name": "B",
      "location": "NJ"
    },
    {
      "name": "A",
      "location": "NY"
    },
    {
      "name": "D",
      "location": "MA"
    }
]
```

And you should use `JArray` instead of `JObject` to parse it so that you can apply filter.

```
JArray jsonArray = JArray.Parse(jsonString);
var match = jsonArray.Where(i => i["name"].ToString() == "A" && i["location"].ToString() == "NY").ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You do know that your json array is incorrect, don't you? An array is within square brackets `[ ... ]`. I assume that is a typing error.

My advice would be to separate your concerns: split your problem into separate parts:

- I have a string in JSON format containing information about Persons (?), and I need to convert this into a sequence of Persons
- I have a sequence of Persons, I need only those Persons with a certain Name and Location.

If you do this, your code will be easier to understand, more reusable, easier to test and easier to change. Who does not want that?

#### Convert string to a sequence of Persons

For this I write an extension function. This way it looks more like LINQ. See [extension methods demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Location {get; set;}

    ... // other properties
}

// Converts a JToken to a Person:
public static Person ToPerson(this JToken token)
{
    // TODO: decide what to do if token == null. Return null?
    Person person = token.ToObject<Person>();
    return person;
}

// Converts JSON string to sequence of Persons
public static IEnumerable<Person> ToPersons(this string jsonText)
{
    // TODO: exception if jsonText null, or incorrect
    IEnumerable<JToken> jsonArray = JArray.Parse(jsonString);
    foreach (JToken token in jsonArray)
    {
        Person person = token.ToPerson();
        yield return person;
    }
}
```

Usage looks like LINQ ToList():

```
string jsonText = ...
IEnumerable<Person> persons = jsonText.ToPersons();
```

#### Keep only Persons with certain name and location

After you've converted the json to a sequence of Persons, the rest is standard LINQ

```
const int name = "John Doe";
const int location = "New York City";
string jsonText = ...

var result = jsonText.ToPersons()
    .Where(person => person.Name == name && person.Location == location);
```

#### Advantages of this separation of concerns

This Separation has several advantages:

- You can reuse `ToPersons()` for other LINQ statements: "give me all elderly Persons", "give me the cities where my Persons live".
- It is easier to test: just create an array of test persons as a source for your LINQ statements
- It is easier to understand: people who read your LINQ statements don't have to bother anymore about the conversion: they know the conversion is used already in a lot of other places, and the test software succeeds, hence you can trust the conversion.
- It is easier to change: if you want to add a PostCode to your Persons, go ahead, your LINQ statements won't change, only `ToPerson()`