# Extracting data from JSON structure in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

JSON data:

```
{
    "return": {
        "output01": "Test request success!!",
        "output02": "test request"
    }
}
```

C# code:

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
JToken jToken = obj["return"];

foreach (JToken item in jToken)
{
     string output1_param = item["output01"].ToString();
     string output2_param = item["output02"].ToString();
}
```

Think of a repeat case.

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot access child value on
> Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty.'

What's wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty -Error happens while checking JObject using LinQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49254281/cannot-access-child-value-on-newtonsoft-json-linq-jproperty-error-happens-while)

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why not deserialize to a proper model?

Comment: `jToken["output01"].ToString()` would be enough, you don't that `foreach` loop.

Comment: cast `jToken` to `JObject` and iterate properties?

Comment: `item` is already one of the children. _They_ don't have properties `output01` or `output02`.

Comment: If there are several "return" items, I will put them in the datatable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`item` is a `JProperty`, so it does not [support](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/c9e12bc4755c786a9073dddf1be14cd27823a498/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JToken.cs#L326) indexer by object key (for example `string` one). You need either strip `foreach`:

```
JToken jToken = obj["return"];
string output1_param = jToken["output01"].ToString();
string output2_param = jToken["output02"].ToString();
```

Or work with `Values` of `item`, for example via `First`:

```cs
foreach (JToken item in jToken)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.First.ToString());
}
```

Also in this case casting to `JProperty` in `foreach` is also an option:

```cs
foreach (JProperty item in jToken)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.Name} - {item.Value}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as you can see in [This Link](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/52e257ee57899296d81a868b32300f0b3cfeacbe/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JToken.cs#L328), indexer of JToken does not implemented and your code tries to using indexer of JToken.

When you call GetEnumerator of jToken, in this sample you will get just single element which is JProperty, so calling indexer of JProperty(by using string key) which implemented JToken will try using this indexer and throws exception.

what happens if you call using this way:

```
jToken["output01"].ToString();
```

in this pattern you are using indexer of JObject, which iterates over ChildrenTokens of JObject and give you values.

as [Guru](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2501279/guru-stron) said you must read value using value field or use First element.